# Spring boot REST Controller redirect issue

Tags: spring-boot, rest, kotlin, redirect

I wrote a controller method to return a 302 with the location header. On the consumer side I was expecting to receive exactly that but in turn I get a 200 with the content of the location URL in the body right off the server response.

example code:

```
@GetMapping("/example/{id}")
    fun getRedirect(@PathVariable id: UUID): ResponseEntity<*> = 
referenceRepo.load(id).run {
if (this.isExternal()) {
ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.FOUND).location(this.url!!.toURI())
                        .build()
} else {
ResponseEntity.ok(this)
}
```

If I remove the location setup I do get the redirect status code. Am I missing something in spring here? I wasn't expecting the location header to be followed up by spring ouput pipeline.

Comment: nvm I was played by postman. It's automatically following the redirect. The endpoint is returning what I was expecting.

Answer (score 0):

tl;dr; Use curl and not any other fancy tool when testing a problematic rest endpoint.

This feels so stupid but I finally realized it was postman the one who was following the redirect. My endpoint is returning correctly tho.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).